# Consolidating different worksheets together in One however loop fails when any file is missing

Tags: vba

I have being using the below code since long however whenever new month starts at its first day when consolidation is run and one single file is missing the macro fails.

```
strListSheet = "Processors List"

On Error GoTo ErrH
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
Range("D8").Select

'this is the main loop, we will open the files one by one and copy their data into the masterdata sheet
Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    strFileName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & ActiveCell.Value
    strCopyRange = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)
    strWhereToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    strStartCellColName = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5), 2, 1)

    Application.Workbooks.Open strFileName, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Range(strCopyRange).Select
    Selection.Copy

    currentWB.Activate
    Sheets(strWhereToCopy).Select
    lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn(strStartCellColName)
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    dataWB.Close False
    Sheets(strListSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("Processors List").Activate
Range("P2").Select
Exit Sub
```

The loop ends whenever if any file is missing.
THe loop should move to the next cell to check the details consolidating remaining sheets.

Regards,

VIpul

Comment: Add validation to see if the file exists before attempting to open the file: `If Len(Dir(strFileName)) > 0 Then [import]`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. You Rock !!!